# Output all columns with a header row greater than 0 onto another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range in Sheet 1 from J11 to BYW3000. Row 11 for each column either contains 0 or a number greater than 0. I want to output the entire column for each column that has a number greater than 0 in that column's Row 11 onto sheet 2, all of which need to be next to each other on sheet 2. I don't have any code as I am new to VBA and don't know the syntax save for sub(). Would someone be able to help with that?

In short, paste all the columns from sheet 1 that have a value greater than 0 in the heading row onto sheet 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have edited your code below but it seems to bug out at the for each statement with the error Object does not support property. Could it be with my "a" declaration?

I just needed to put  <>"" instead of 0 and declare what COL was. Thank you very much for your help, Yasser. I would like to know how the code actually functions if you have the time for a brief explanation. Than

```
Dim c As Range, COL As Long, a As Worksheet, b As Worksheet


Set a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SOLVER")
Set b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FEB Test")

COL = 9

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In a.Range("J11").CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            COL = COL + 1
            With a
                .Range(.Cells(11, c.Column), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row, c.Column)).Copy b.Cells(11, COL)
            End With
        End If
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Please include the code you are using in your question and explain the problems you are having with it.

Comment: Please do not add the "excel-vba" tag. This tag is pending deletion (let's see if that ever happens).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Demo()
Dim c As Range, col As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In Sheet1.Range("J11").CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Cells
        If c.Value > 0 Then
            col = col + 1
            With Sheet1
                .Range(.Cells(11, c.Column), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row, c.Column)).Copy Sheet2.Cells(1, col)
            End With
        End If
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the hep Yasser. I have responded to your comment in my edited question. I seem to have trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Define a and b in your code as worksheet. Example : Dim a as Worksheet

Comment: Still have the same issue with the run time error in the code above? Object doesn't support this property or method '438'

Comment: In this line `For Each C In A.Range("J11").CurrentRegion.Rows(1).cell` >> `cell` should be `Cells`

Comment: Great, it seems to be working, but is it possible to output this in the column in the same row starting in column J of new ("FEB Test") Sheet? Such that if Solver.cell("N11") was the first column header to contain a value >0, the column would be outputted on the FEB TESt sheet starting in J11 and then so on sequentially?

Comment: In this line `.Copy Sheet2.Cells(1, col)` change row 1 to the row you desired.

Comment: This worked, I have throw my final code into my original answer. Thanks so much for your help.